# Silverlight wcf connection error

Tags: wcf, silverlight, cross-domain, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I'm about a month away developing my silverlight application (this is my first). Everything went rather smoothly until today, when out of the blue I started getting this message:

> An error occurred while trying to make a request to URI 'http://localhost:2682/Services/Authentication/LoginService.svc'. This could be due to attempting to access a service in a cross-domain way without a proper cross-domain policy in place, or a policy that is unsuitable for SOAP services. You may need to contact the owner of the service to publish a cross-domain policy file and to ensure it allows SOAP-related HTTP headers to be sent. This error may also be caused by using internal types in the web service proxy without using the InternalsVisibleToAttribute attribute. Please see the inner exception for more details.

I'm using WCF Services and this issue never appeared until now.
I've added a clientdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml file to my [projectname].web folder, and re-wrote them about a 1000 different ways.
I've also used Fiddler and it shows me that the error is on both those files, the error is

> [Fiddler] The socket connection to localhost failed. 
> ErrorCode: 10061. 
> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2682

I've searched the error "10061" and it has to do with socket definition. But I couldn't find any solution to that.

Don't know if it has anything to do with it, but my "ASP.net Development Server" port is 6939.

Keep in mind that the app has NOT been deployed, so this is only happening locally. I'm using MS VS 2010 and MS SQL Server 2008.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this a silverlight issue??

On a last note, I haven't changed anything on Port, socket or service configuration. Last thing I was doing was editing a XAML file on client side and and the app started throwing me this error.

Need help, can't do anything until this is solved!!!!
Thanks.

Comment: is you silverlight app and wcf service are two separate visual studio solutions?

Comment: I think the visual studio web server switches the port number automatically sometimes. If the port number is not the same as when you did "add service reference" it will fail if it changes. Try using IIS instead. That is probably what you will deploy to eventually anyway so it makes sense to use it during development.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh no, they are on the same project. I've already figured the problem but no the cause. Thanks

Comment: @HenrikSöderlund thanks for the tip, that's exactly what happened. Never thought about that until now, I'm going to have a look at IIS and make the necessary modifications. Thanks

Comment: you can even try creating client proxy instance from code instead of relying on ServiceReferences.ClientConfig

Answer (score 1):

i think you are using you app on localhost and a dynamic port is getting assigned and this port is not fixed and every run and that causes the refuse problem. if you want to fix this, create a solid url for example,

`http://localhost/apps/Services/Authentication/LoginService.svc`

Answer (score 0):

Well, last night, just before I went to bed, I noticed something odd. In my "ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" file, the endpoint ports for each one of my services where diferent from the ones the silverlight machine used, so going on a hunch (and because I was reaching my sanity breakpoint) I decided to eliminate all my Service References and re-add them again.

I worked... go figure. Still don't know why this happened and if anyone could shed some light on the subject, I would appreciate it. It's kinda of annoying having to re-add all my services references. Right now I have only 6 of them, but in the near future they may go over 20, and if this happens again... well, it's going to be a real pain...

Thanks